# MCMC convergence vs autocorrelation

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

I am using Metropolis-Hastings to generate samples from what I assume to be the posterior. At some point, the samples will converge - I cannot see how they would not since they all share the proposal distribution which must have some sort of mean.

Now I hear a lot of people talking about that you want to minimize autocorrelation for the samples. This does not make sense to me when you take convergence into consideration; You usually discard the initial samples up until every parameter has converged, right. Say I am running multiple chains and the samples all converge to the same points (again, I cannot see how this cannot happen since distributions have means) and so this value would be the ideal sample because then you could perfectly approximate things like intergrals, am I right?`

So why dont you *just* go for convergence and try to move towards a given value for your parameters (at this points after the burn-in phase, the autocorrelation would of course be high since the sample are all the same but why is this bad?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trajectories themselves generally aren't convergent, only the empirical distribution of a trajectory is convergent (under ergodicity assumptions which in the setting of M-H are extremely mild).

That being said, it is true that even arbitrarily strong autocorrelation will not destroy convergence, but it will reduce the convergence rate. For some intuition, consider a 2 state chain with a matrix like

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1-10^{-6} & 10^{-6} \\
10^{-6} & 1-10^{-6} \end{bmatrix}.$$

One can see by inspection that $\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix}$ is the invariant distribution. But what is the convergence rate to that when starting from state 1? You will spend somewhere around a million time steps at state 1, then jump to state 2, then stay there for around a million time steps, etc. It typically takes a very long time for the empirical distribution to even stop being $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, and then when a jump to state 2 finally happens, change will be very slow (since you accumulated so many time steps in state 1 already). The problem is that the probability that the next state in the trajectory will be the same as the current one is very high, in other words the problem is in the autocorrelation.

Contrast this with an extreme case like $\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix}$ where actually you're drawing from the target distribution right from the start.

Comment: "You will spend somewhere around a million time steps at state 1, then jump to state 2, then stay there for around a million time steps, etc." doesn't it take that long because we are close to a mean? And isn't sampling means good because they must be representing the posterior that we are going for? So why not just stop sampling when we reached 1/2 and then just let all of our samples be 1/2 (or [1/2 
 1/2]). I just cannot see why you wouldn't stop when you have found the mean I guess. Hope you got the main point of what I said :))

Comment: @step You will take a very long time to actually reach an empirical distribution anywhere near $\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix}$ in this situation, particularly if you are retaining all samples (also, burn-in will not really do anything in this situation). Try running it, this is simple enough to program and should run in a few seconds at most when you're done.

Comment: And so why do you care about the burn-in phase (I mean you are literally moving towards more samples closer to the what might be the mean of the posterior for a parameter)?

Comment: @step In general the point of the burn-in phase is to "forget" about where you started the process. This is typically not as important as retaining every $N$ samples to reduce the effect of autocorrelation; indeed burning in doesn't really do anything at all in the example I used (though it does do something in more complicated situations).

Comment: Hmm okay. But isn't the point of MCMC like Metropolis to sample from a some probability (the posterior) that you actually don't know. If do not think I understand why you just always go for reaching the mean which is only represented by the convergence and not autocorrelation.  Are you saying that autocorrelation is also to shorten the time to reach the mean/somewhere at the mode of the posterior? I feel like the two quantities contrast each other and that is why I cannot see any reason to use them together. like isn't it impossible to minimize autocorrelation and reach the mode of posterior?

Comment: So like if I am trying to find optimal parameters that otherwise were given by a posterior that I do not know (I know the likelihood and prior though), then for each sample the chain starts to converge towards a given value. Is this value not the expected/optimal parameter? I will give you time to answer :)

Comment: @step The point is that autocorrelation reduces the convergence rate relative to independent samples, so you want to reduce it to accelerate convergence. It may help here to focus on just the case of approximating an invariant distribution on a finite state space, rather than thinking about parameters.

Comment: Ah okay :) But for instance I know that you can use the samples to approximate integrals - but will this integral  be approximated the best if all you only start picking sampling when you see the "mean" or if you picked samples randomly with very little autocorrelation? Wouldn't the second case just itself have a mean as the true mean of the posterior? So why care? I did did read your last comment but do not think I got it completely. I know may be asking questions you think are a little less clever but you seem like the man to seek for help so I just spit it out :D

Comment: Because the Monte Carlo approximations only only for "independent" samples but can you convince why (if it is) it is not better to use only samples that seem to be the mean and thus happens to have high autocorrelation/dependence. I think this is where one of the bigger problems lie. I would be able to see the importance of low autocorrelation if you cannot just use samples of the mean (samples that all have the same value) but if you can, it must be that you use autocorrelation only to increase the convergence rate

Comment: "if you cannot just use samples of the mean (samples that all have the same value)" is that you cannot use the essentially the same samples (although this is the mean and thus most representative sample). Now I stop spamming

Comment: @step The point is that your samples from MCMC when you are trying to approximate the mean of the invariant distribution won't just converge on the mean. The empirical mean will do that, but the actual samples from the MCMC won't do anything of the sort. Instead you will asymptotically be drawing samples from the invariant distribution, but in a highly non-independent fashion, in principle.

Comment: What do you mean by "empirical mean" - I am currently running an implementation of Metropolis and it always ends up the at the same value after a big amount of samples.

Comment: Or is autocorrelation really just a tool to 1) let you do things like Monte Carlo approximations without actually have samples that might themselves be close to the actual mean (expected value)  and 2) let you converge faster by optimizing the correlation of samples (by maybe adjusting the variance)?

Comment: @step What do you mean when you say it ends up at the same value? When I say the empirical mean I mean $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i)$ where $X_i$ are the samples generated by the chain and the goal is to estimate $E[f(X)]$ when $X$ is distributed against the invariant distribution of the chain. Alternately it could be $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f(X_{ki})$ where $k$ is an integer $>1$. In either case it is not typical for the samples *themselves* to cluster tightly around $E[f(X)]$.

Comment: Aha I get what you mean then. Was my last comment correct? And so are you saying that it is possible to get "stuck" somewhere (even though you maybe calculated R hat for 20 different chains and they all moved to this area) without it actually being very close to E[f(X)]?

Comment: That will be the final questions for me though. I will accept your answer then :)

Comment: @step Again consider my example here, where $f(x)=x$, so you're waiting for convergence to 1.5 and the values you can get at all are between 1 and 2. You will see exactly 1 for a million or so iterations, and then gradually drift towards 1.5, perhaps past it, and then continue oscillating like that. The fluctuations will be quite large until you've already measured a number of iterations much larger than 1 million.